# Chef search api internet interface

Tags: chef-infra

I'm currently using the following code:

```
elastic_ip = search(:node, 'roles:elastic',  
                        filter_result: {
                          'ip' => ['ipaddress']
                        })
```

The problem is that I have more than one network interface, and it gives me a wrong one.

How can I ask for the different network interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohai collects info on all interfaces under `node[‘network’][‘interfaces’]` which you can get an address from, though you’ll need some way to know which one is correct.`node[’ipaddress’]’ comes from the interface associated with the default route.

Comment: How I can find with search api for [‘network’][‘interfaces’] and then ["network"]["interfaces"][iface_name]["addresses"]?

Comment: You would have to use partial search to filter on `['network', 'interfaces']` and the process further locally, the data isn't really set up to work nicely with filtering at the search level. If you request an intermediary key like that with `filter_result` you'll get the whole hash underneath it, so pretty easy to make it work.